# Combo ou Dropdownlist exibir um Texto de acordo com o seu value

Tags: c#, webforms

Faço uma pesquisa no meu BD e trago, digamos, o número 237. Esse é o value da minha Combo que equivale ao texto Bradesco S/A. Então, gostaria que a Dopdownlist exibisse esse texto Bradesco S/A quando eu passar o value(237). Não estou conseguindo fazer isso funcionar. Veja o que eu já fiz.

```
for (int i = 0; i < cmbBancos.Items.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        if (cmbBancos.Items[i].Value == nm_banco)
                        {
                            cmbBancos_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                            //cmbBancos.Text = cmbBancos.Items[i].Text.ToString();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
```

Da forma acima, não funciona e nem com o código comentado, também não. Alguém sabe como fazer isso funcionar?

Uso WebForm e C#.

Comment: Esse dropdown é populado com os números do banco? Você quer que o valor exibido seja "Bradesco S/A" e o valor seja 237? É isso?

Comment: @pnet pode colocar o código de como está sendo carregado o seu combo?

Comment: O combo já vem carregado. Todos os banco que atuam no Brasil já estão no combo e seus respectivos números(value). Quando eu digito o cpf ou cnpj de um cliente, aí a busca vai no meu sistema e pega lá o banco, conta e etc.. desse cliente. Só peciso que a combo exiba esse nome de banco passando um value para ele. Já está tudo cadastrado, tudo mesmo. Só não sei como mostrar na combo automaticamente quando o value for passado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que isso lhe atenderá:

```
cmbBancos.SelectedValue = "237";
```

Mas isso só irá funcionar caso vc tenha carregado o DropDownList passando o Texto e o Valor, exemplo:

```
cmbBancos.Items.Add(New ListItem("Bradesco S/A", "237"))
```

Comment: A combo já entra preenchida com todos os bancos atuantes no Brasil. Só quero mesmo é exibir o texto de acordo com o value encontrado no meu BD.

Comment: @pnet Se na sua DropDownList além de ter inserido o Texto do banco, também exista o Valor, dessa forma que eu coloquei irá funcionar!